# Capybara Poltergeist failed to reach server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

capybara's

```
visit '/'
```

command is causing poltergeist driver to error: Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError: Request to 'http://127.0.0.1:50142/' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status

The screenshot shows a rendered page.

I ruled out

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

causing the problem. The error happens whether true or false.

I don't have any 3rd party websites being loaded.

The first part of the test works. It's just the visit command causing the error.

```
it 'should have email input' do
    my_login_func
    expect(page).to have_selector("input[type=email]")

    visit '/'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
When I switched my driver back to webkit instead of poltergeist. I got the error. I had an iframe on the page that wasn't loading.

Poltergeist didn't complain about it. Webkit did.